# MoviePy: linspace() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dtype'

Tags: python, python-2.7, moviepy

`Python 2.7.16`

I want to work with `moviepy` on an audio file, but I always get this error. For example, I want to do anything with `moviepy`, but without involving audio files, it does it without any problem, but when I want to do something with audio it explodes. It seems to me that the problem is with the NumPy library.

Sorry for not putting more information, I have never used python before, what else can I add to complete my question?

[image]

Comment: You are correct that the issue is related to NumPy (most likely). Can you please tell me what version you're running? `python -c "import numpy; print(numpy.__version__)"`

Comment: The version is the  1.8.0rc1

Comment: @PaulBurkart Your comment made me think if the problem was the version, I saw that the current version of numpy is much older than the one I have, I ran the command pip install --upgrade numpy and now everything works fine, thank you very much.

Comment: The dtype argument was added to linspace in 1.9.0, so your version of NumPy is too early. Try downloading the wheel from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy) and then install it using `pip install <path to wheel>`

Comment: Awesome! Glad it's all working out. I'll add a clean answer to this in case anyone else has the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has to do with your version of NumPy, as the `dtype` argument was added to linspace in 1.9.0. As you've indicated you're currently using version 1.8.0rc1.

There are two ways to upgrade NumPy. You can either download the wheel directly from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy) and install it manually with `pip install /path/to/downloaded/wheel`, or you can use the `pip install --upgrade numpy` command. If pip is outdated however, this command may not fetch the latest numpy version.